# How to search in a file by field

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, awk

I have this input:

```
AB1       oo1       FE11         aq 
cd7       pp9       xw11         as
md1       Al1       as101        sd   
ak5       AB1       aw1          sd
ci6       QB7       cr12         sw
do0       RB1       AB1          sq
```

and need this output:  `AB1` in the field  `1` and `2` and `3`

I tried this but there is something wrong:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { if ($i ~/AB1/) } print $i }' file name
```

Is thre any thing wrong with my code? Pleaase, tell me and if you have better cods show it to me.

Thank you all

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you just want to check if a line contains `AB1`?

Comment: i want   the number of  every field  contain the ("AB") so as in this example AB in the field 1,2,3 but not in  4th field ,so i need cod that tell me wich field contain AB1 .hope to be clear

Comment: So you would like the output of your command to be a single line with numbers like `"1 2 3"` ?

Answer (score 3):

You have some syntax errors in your code:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { if ($i ~/AB1/) } print $i }' file name
```

the closing `}` in `if ($i ~/AB1/) }` is a mistake, the `if` needs a command there, and you need a closing `}` to match the very first `{`, like this:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { if ($i ~/AB1/) print $i }}' file name
```

with this syntax error corrected, the output is:

```
AB1
AB1
AB1
```

To print the number of the field with the value `AB1`, I would write like this:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) if ($i == "AB1") print i }' file
1
2
3
```

Comment: thank you alot janos but i want the number of field that contain AB1

Comment: @mahmoud you're welcome, and I updated my answer according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

corrected line of code
`awk '{ for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { if ($i ~/AB1/) print $i }}' file name`

original

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { if ($i ~/AB1/) } print $i }' file name
```

the problem was bracket u placed it at wrong place

Answer (score 0):

If you want "string in the fields: n n n":

```
awk -v string="AB1" '

              {   if ( maxNF < NF ) {   maxNF = NF ; } }

    $0~string {   we_found_it=1 ;
                  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                  {  if ( $i ~ string ) {  found_in[i]++ ; }
                  }
               }

     END       {  if ( we_found_it == 1 )
                  {   printf "%s in the fields: ", string ;
                      for (i=1; i<=maxNF ; i++)
                      {   if (found_in[i]>0)
                          {  printf "%s ", i ;
                          }
                      }
                   }
                   else
                   {   printf "%s was NOT found in any fields.", string ;
                   }
                }    '
```

This matches the string anywhere in the field (ex: "...AB1..." matches)

If you prefer an exact match:

```
awk -v string="AB1" '

              {   if ( maxNF < NF ) {   maxNF = NF ; } }

    $0~string {   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                  {  if ( $i == string ) 
                     {   we_found_it=1 ;
                         found_in[i]++ ;
                     }
                  }
               }

     END       {  if ( we_found_it == 1 )
                  {   printf "%s in the fields: ", string ;
                      for (i=1; i<=maxNF ; i++)
                      {   if (found_in[i]>0)
                          {  printf "%s ", i ;
                          }
                      }
                   }
                   else
                   {   printf "%s was NOT found in any fields.", string ;
                   }
                }    '
```

That one matches exactly (ie: "AB1" matches "AB1", but not "...AB1kkk")

Comment: I know it's long and a bit ugly, but I hope it is readable/understandable ^^